# Change WHM password via PHP?

Tags: php, scripting, cpanel, whm

Is there a PHP script or piece of code I can type to change a WHM account's password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean with *WHM* but if you mean what I mean, then [this class](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/4150.html) might help you.

> This class can be used to manipulate Cpanel/WHM hosting accounts using the XML Web services API.
>
> It can establish secure HTTP connections to a Web server to manage Cpanel/WHM accounts and authenticates on behalf of a given Cpanel user.
>
> The class can execute several types of requests:
>
> - Retrieve the XML API version
> - Retrieve the server host name
> - List the active hosting accounts
> - List the available packages
> - Create a new account
> - Retrieve a summary about an account
> - Change the password of an account
> - Suspend, unsuspend and terminate an account
> - Upgrade or downgrade a package